# What HTML and CSS does Safari rely on for Reader View?

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having a hard time getting a web page to show up properly in Safari's Reader View. I've got ARTICLE tags and H2's but the second half of my page is missing in the Reader View on an iPhone 6. See http://marcus.em.id.au/interspan/about.html

Presumably there is some additional semantic HTML which I need. You'd have thought it would be as simple as setting up print styles but there's very little literature on this...

(Please don't refer me to old posts from 2011 or 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingWiththeReader/WorkingWiththeReader.html which don't answer the question.)

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader-html

Comment: Thanks @user7234396 - looks promising. I'll have a look when I get back to this project.

Comment: I am also struggling to definition (and limits), better across browsers, Firefox, Chrome, Safari. For example: Is Reader View supposed to be supported on localhost. Which exact HTML tags will be displayed, which not.